# reCAPTCHA authenticates as valid even for two incorrect words

Tags: security, captcha, recaptcha

Just to give a background for my question, I am using [Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org) for a website I run. Vanilla Forums comes with baked-in support for using reCAPTCHA to authenticate new registrations on the website, which I have enabled. Recently on my forum, however, I have seen a spike in spam registrations (obvious 'spammy' usernames, same email address used, et al.)

I looked into this to try to see how spambots could be getting past the reCAPTCHA verification. I know that in reCAPTCHA, [one of the words is known by the system and the other isn't](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore), so [it is possible that a form submit might validate even if one incorrect word is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429759/recaptcha-still-submits-form-when-one-word-invalid).

So I tried out a couple of things on the registration form on my site, by entering invalid reCAPTCHA inputs. I found that...

- If the number of characters entered per word is correct
- The answer response entered for BOTH words is entered correctly EXCEPT FOR by one character

...no reCAPTCHA error is thrown.

I don't think this issue is isolated to Vanilla Forum either. When you go the the [demo page for reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore), try this yourself. Enter two words, correct number of characters, but the words themselves off by one character - with 'similar' looking characters (like, an 'a' instead of a 'd', 'v' instead of 'w'.)

Is there something wrong with Vanilla's implementation of reCAPTCHA or is this a known issue with reCAPTCHA itself? (You can [test Vanilla's registration form here](http://vanillaforums.org/discussions).)

Possibly related: [Has reCaptcha been cracked / hacked / OCR'd / defeated / broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448963/has-recaptcha-been-cracked-hacked-ocrd-defeated-broken)

Comment: I have experienced same behavior and at times it can be more than two characters or even one less character

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just [found the answer in the reCAPTCHA wiki](http://web.archive.org/web/20100328103929/http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/FAQ#reCAPTCHA_is_accepting_incorrect_words):

> On the verification word, reCAPTCHA
>   **intentionally allows an "off by one"
>   error** depending on how much we trust
>   the user giving the solution. This
>   increases the user experience without
>   impacting security. reCAPTCHA
>   engineers monitor this functionality
>   for abuse.

Comment: That link doesn't work. I couldn't find any wiki.recaptcha.net website. Wouldn't all the documentation be on Google now that Google bought reCAPTCHA from Carnegie-Mellon.

Comment: @FeralOink: Updated to change it to a Wayback Machine cache of the page. I can't find equivalent documentation on reCAPTCHA site any more.

Comment: +1 Thank you! It is unfortunate that the reCAPTCHA wiki site went off-line. A real loss, as it had so much good information, given the many references I have seen on SE alone. FYI, at least the reCAPTCHA Google group remains online and active (the wiki mentioned it):  http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha?hl=en