# How to fix google recaptcha?

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha

[image]

The captcha : vista aperto

I input "vista", then I click button login. It's success to login. Should it not succeed to login, because the captcha incomplete.

whether the process is so?
or is there a way to fix?

I using library recaptcha. I using codeigniter framework. My library is like this :

```
class Google_recaptcha
{
    function check_captcha($private_key, $remote_ip, $challenge, $response)
    {   
        if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/', $response))
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->library('scurl');
            $array['site'] = 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify';
            $array['post'] = 'privatekey='.$private_key.'&remoteip='.$remote_ip.'&challenge='.$challenge.'&response='.$response;
            $array['referer'] = '';
            $array['method'] = 'POST';

            $response = $CI->scurl->scurl($array);
            $response = explode("\n", $response);
        }
        else
            $response = array('false');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recaptcha still submits form when one word invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429759/recaptcha-still-submits-form-when-one-word-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use those old script. Try reCaptcha. It is much better. Just click authorization without typing anything. Sometimes you have to choose one kind of picture. From Google's web API you can control security level. 
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

Answer (score 0):

this is so old recapcha version . google not support an. try new version recapcha . it easy to navigate with form submit & validate run by google . 
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html

& also its have reCAPTCHA library for CodeIgniter 
https://github.com/appleboy/CodeIgniter-reCAPTCHA

example code
http://www.technicalkeeda.com/php-codeigniter/google-new-recaptcha